# Does there exist a sequence that has countably infinite convergent subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that for every natural number $n$ there is a sequence with exactly $n$ convergent subsequences, where I consider two subsequences to be the same if they are equal as sequences (even if they correspond to different subsets of the original index set). For example take a sequence with $n-1$ ones and zeroes afterward. A sequence like $a_n=1/n$ has uncountably infinitely many convergent subsequences since every subsequence is convergent and all the terms are distinct. I am wondering if there exists a sequence with countably infinitely many convergent subsequences.

Comment: I don't understand your first example. If a sequence is infinite, it has uncountably many subsequences, so you have uncountably many convergent subsequences if there is at least one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because it is unclear. The first  example you give does not work as you say tit does..

Comment: The examples *do* work if sequences with identical entries aren't distinguished. If a sequence follows $n-1$ copies of $1$ with $0$s, the only subsequences are those with $0$ to $n-1$ copies of $1$ followed by $0$s, so there are $n$ of those.

Comment: Perhaps the issue to clarify is what makes two subsequences count as two *distinct* subsequences.  From your example it seems that you only require that some pair of corresponding entries differ as sequences, not that their limits are different or that they have all or infinitely many different entries.

Comment: @J.G. Ah! Ok. That interpretation makes sense, thanks. We are taking subsequences and reindexing them.

Comment: I consider sequences as functions from $N$ to $R$ so they are different if they have different numbers on same indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a_n=p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$. If a subsequence converges, it converges to a prime $p$, in which case except for finitely many initial terms, the sequence is eventually constant with value $p$. But the number of initial terms is arbitrary.

Comment: I am still worried that there are uncountably many options for a fixed limit p.

Comment: No, because ${\mathbb N}^{<\infty}$ is countable.

Comment: @GregorKikelj There are only countably many sequences of integers that are eventually constant.

Comment: Just to check if I understand it. Would the sequence 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2... work by the same argument?

Comment: Yes, actually. I wanted countably many limit points, but that was not one of your requirements.

Comment: Why not just $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,\cdots$?

Answer (score 3):

An easy example is the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$. In order for a subsequence to be convergent it must eventually be constant, which means there is some initial sequence with the other digit, and there are countably many options for that initial sequence.